# How to have dynamic image on Xamarin Form Header?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, openweathermap

I am working on Xamarin form in which header title will have weather temperature and weather icon on its right side.

For example

New York 60' F    SunnyIcon

I am using openweather api to fetch the data.

Problem is, I am not able to create a dynamic image holder on the Xamarin Form Header.

How to have a dynamic image on the Xamarin Form Header?

Attached is a sample app which i am working on based on source code which i downloaded from github ...

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Header"?  The Navigation bar?  Or something else?  Header does not have any specific meaning in XF.

Comment: @jason, yes i mentioned about Navigation bar.

Comment: @Jason, i have attached the screenshot of my sample app .. in which you can see the Weather Icon in Temperature  field .. , I need to show that icon along with the City Name, Temperature followed by icon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Header," but if you're trying to add an icon to the `Navigation Bar`, you can do that by calling `ToolbarItems.add()` in the constructor of your page like this:

```
    public myPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Weather", "WeatherIcon.png", async () =>
        {
            //Code to Execute when Icon is tapped
        }));
    }
```

When adding the `ToolbarItem`, the first parameter is the name of the item, the second is the name of the image that will be displayed at the end of the Navigation bar, and the last one is optional which creates a method that is executed when the icon is tapped.

If you need the icon to be different depending on the current weather, you can do that like this:

```
    public myPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string weatherIconString = "";
        if(weather.isSunny) // Edit contition however you need
            weatherIconString = "SunnyIcon.png";
        else
            weatherIconString = "CloudyIcon.png";

        ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Weather", weatherIconString));
    }
```

Comment: I mentioned Header , which is where we mention Page.Title. I need to include weather icon along with the Page.Title.  Where we can have a back arrow icon or Hamburger Icon ... However, i don't have a problem with static images. I am having issue only with dynamic image..

Comment: The header your mentioning is the Navigation Bar, if you just want to add a picture, you can use this code and remove the third constructor so nothing will happen when it's clicked on.

Comment: Do you mean that there are different images that could be put in the navigation bar?  If so, you can write if statements that will change the value of the picture.  I'll edit my post to show this.

Comment: this is weather icon ..from openweather .. https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions      - I need to display it .. depending on current weather

Comment: Xamarin Forms ToolbarItem doesn't support Icons from a Uri.  In order to use the icons from openweathermap.org in a Xamarin Forms project, you either need to display the icon on the page itself, and not in the Navigation bar, or you need to download the images, and put them in the corresponding Project Image folders.  Check out developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/ for more info

Comment: thank you again. For now,  i have downloaded the open weather icons and trying to display based on the weather icon code. Eventually, we will be using our own weather icons for the weather. I am having difficult on showing this downloaded weather icons on dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom renderer like this: and the result:
[image]

```
 public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        //I'm getting width and height so i can rescale the image
        nfloat navigationBarWidth = NavigationBar.Frame.Width;
        nfloat navigationBarHeight = NavigationBar.Frame.Height;

        //you can load image from your bundle,so you can add your weather icons on bundle -> under Resources folder
        var img = UIImage.FromBundle("navigationbarbackground.jpg");
        //create image context to draw image
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(new CGSize(navigationBarWidth, navigationBarHeight), true, 0);
        //I'm filling the background with a color so it is the same as with my background image color    
        UIColor.FromRGB(54, 60, 65).SetFill();
        UIGraphics.RectFill(new CGRect(0, 0, navigationBarWidth, navigationBarHeight));
        //draw your image according to the coordinates of the navigation bar, i put it to the right top with a small right padding,
        //you have to play with coordinates according to your needs
        img.Draw(new CGRect(navigationBarWidth - navigationBarHeight - 30,//move 30px to the left (do not paste to right border :))
            0, navigationBarHeight, navigationBarHeight));
        UIImage backgroundImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, UIBarMetrics.Default);

        //bonus :) change your title color
        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
        {
            TextColor = UIColor.White,
        });

        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }
}
```